# WP: How do I allow the Editor to only have access to a specific page?

Tags: wordpress

There is already a plugin that limits the sections that a user can access in the admin panel.

But I wanted it to limit access to just a single page. In other words, you can only edit a page, and can not see the other pages!

Is there a plugin that does this?

The plugin Adminimize can limit access to pages, but can not limit the single page, I think!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this plugin, it is free.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/pagerestrict/

Comment: I really want to hide! For example, a user accesses the admin panel and can see the page in the page list, but another user can not even know that a certain page exists.